# How to do In highchart tooltip display the first 100 characters and then say "See more .."?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, highcharts

```
tooltip: {
    style: {
        whiteSpace: 'normal'
    },
    xDateFormat: '%b %e, %Y', //%a %H:%M
        useHTML: true,
        pointFormatter: function () {
        var ToolTippointFormathtm='';
        ToolTippointFormathtm += '<div class="noteContent" style="white-space:normal;">';
        ToolTippointFormathtm += '<div style="" class="more textLimit">' + this.noteText + '</div>';
        if(this.noteText.length>99){
            ToolTippointFormathtm += '<a data-series="'+this.series.index+'" href="javascript:;" class="seeMoreLink" onclick="fnMoreLess($(this))">See more</a>';
        }
        ToolTippointFormathtm += '</div>';
        return ToolTippointFormathtm;
    }
}
```

Its showing in tooltip, but whenever I'm trying to click see more and the tooltip area wont expanded but text is expanded.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: In your tooltip style braces specify the height to be 'auto'

Comment: I already check this.

Comment: Did you set it via css or via the javascript braces?

Comment: Both css and script but getting same result.

Comment: Hmmm, normally i would create several hack workarounds, i sometimes won't mind even hacking the library itself. But i guess you should find if it creates an id, class in the dom elements it creates. Such as the noteContent class you created in formatting it. Also see if that could work,

Comment: Could you add `fnMoreLess` method to the question? In general, you need to redraw the tooltip with new content or manually resize the background. Simple changing amount of text won't resize the tooltip - tooltip background is rendered in SVG, so it won't magically resize ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have used CSS toggle to achieve show more/less. Here I used div and p tags, but for best result you have to use `ul li` (list tags). Also there has to be unique id which you can take from, point attr of highcharts

```
<input type="checkbox" class="read-more-state" id="post-2" />
<label for="post-2" class="read-more-trigger"></label>
```

Here tooltip does not expands but scrollbar appears

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/qput4ynq/) demo

```js
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

  chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
  },
  tooltip: {
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0)",
    borderWidth: 0,
    shadow: false,
    useHTML: true,
    formatter: function() {
      full_lengthSt = `Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.`
      string = "";
      if (full_lengthSt.length > 100) {
        string += '<div class="read-more-wrap"><p>' + full_lengthSt.substr(0, 100) + '</p>';
        string += '<p class="read-more-target">' + full_lengthSt.substr(100, full_lengthSt.length - 1) + '</p></div>  <label for="post-2" class="read-more-trigger"></label>'
      } else {
        string += '<div class="read-more-wrap"><p>' + full_lengthSt + '</p></div>'
      }
      return `<div class="MyChartTooltip">
  <input type="checkbox" class="read-more-state" id="post-2" />
  ` + string + `</div>`;
    }
  },

  series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
  }]

});
```

```css
.highcharts-container {
  overflow: visible !important;
}

.read-more-state {
  display: none;
}

.read-more-target {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  transition: .25s ease;
}

.read-more-state:checked~.read-more-wrap .read-more-target {
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: inherit;
  max-height: 999em;
}

.read-more-state~.read-more-trigger:before {
  content: 'Show more';
}

.read-more-state:checked~.read-more-trigger:before {
  content: 'Show less';
}

.read-more-trigger {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  color: #666;
  font-size: .9em;
  line-height: 2;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: .25em;
}

.MyChartTooltip {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 50;
  border: 2px solid rgb(0, 108, 169);
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 9pt;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px
}

.highcharts-tooltip {
  pointer-events: all !important;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js">
</script>
<div id="container" style="height: 300px"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for updating code for me. I really appreciate it. But It would be best if area show without scroll.

Comment: As Pawel Fuss mentioned above in comments tooltip is generated via svg .It will not get resized